# At what time "good day" should be said?

Tags: phrase-usage

If "**good morning**" is between 6:00-12:00 PM, and "**good afternoon**" is between 12:00-6:00 PM then at what time "**good day**" should be said?

Comment: In the US, we solve this problem by not ever saying "Good day".  It sounds a little foreign and formal to this US English speaker.

Comment: @stangdon I live in the US and, while not very common, some people do greet me with "Good day".  I know for a fact that some of these people are born, raised, and live in the US.

Comment: @m_a_s Fair enough!  I was being kind of jocular.  I honestly don't hear "good day" very much, compared to "good morning" or "good afternoon" (or "good evening" for that matter).

Comment: @stangdon I did appreciate the humor there.

Answer (score 2):

Anytime **"during the day"** or **"daytime"**: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/good_day)  / [Amer. Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=good%20day) / [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/good%20day?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)
Generally between sunrise and sunset, if you must put a time for it, usually about 6 AM to 6 PM.

So "good day" can be used instead of "good morning" or "good afternoon" but **not** instead of "good evening".